# Using iconv to convert from UTF-16LE to UTF-8

Tags: linux, utf-16le

Hi I am trying to convert some log files from a Microsoft SQL server, but the files are encoded using UTf-16LE and iconv does not seem to be able to convert them.

I am doing:

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 <filename>
```

I also tried to delete any carriage returns from the end of the line if there are any, but that did not fix it either. If I save it using gedit that works, but this is not a viable solution since I have hundreds of those files.

**EDIT**: Please see the new answer for the missing option

Comment: hello, could you maybe mark one of the answers as accepted? :) Cheers!

Answer (score 68):

I forgot the `-o` switch!

The final command is :

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 <filename> -o <new-filename>
```

Answer (score 36):

The command you specified will output to stdout. You can either use the `-o` parameter, or redirect your output:

with `-o`:

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 infile -o outfile
```

with piping:

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 infile > outfile
```

Both will yield the desired result.

However some versions of iconv (v1 on macOS for example) do not support the `-o` parameter and you will see that the converted text is echoed to stdout. In that case, use the piping option.