# how to remove "^@" from text files in unix?

Tags: linux, unix, text-editor

I am trying to remove "^@" from multiple text files using Unix platform. I have already found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/75130/how-to-remove-this-symbol-with-vim) solution, but it does not work for my case. I also used `sed -i -e 's/^@//g' testfile.txt` and `dos2unix testfile.txt`. 
sample data are put [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/73a6muje9ew3dej/test.txt?dl=0).

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your sample input and expected output?

Comment: I do not know about literal circumflexes and ats. Can you please clarify it? I redo dos2unix but no success. you can also the file in this link.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/73a6muje9ew3dej/test.txt?dl=0

Comment: Can't find `@` in your sample data.

Comment: They are not carriage returns.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you with my little knowledge. ^@ are between all letters.

Comment: @SeyedOmidNabavi You can convert the file to UTF-8 with something like `iconv` or `recode`: `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 < test.txt` or `recode utf16le..utf8 < test.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using iconv to convert from UTF-16LE to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287713/using-iconv-to-convert-from-utf-16le-to-utf-8)

Comment: @Biffen this should be the answer.

Comment: @n.m. Was about to post it, but figured there had to be a duplicate, so I voted to close as such instead.

Comment: @SeyedOmidNabavi As for ‘*Ambiguous input redirect*’: You probably got a `<` or `>` wrong somewhere, or the paths to the files contain spaces (or other special characters) and need to be quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^@` that you're seeing isn't a literal string. It's an escape code for a NUL (character value 0). If you want to remove them all:

```
tr -d '\0' <test.txt >newfile.txt
```

To help diagnose this sort of thing, the `od` (octal dump) utility is handy. I ran this on the test file you linked, to confirm that they were NULs:

```
$ od -c test.txt | head
0000000  \0   A  \0   i  \0   r  \0   Q  \0   u  \0   a  \0   l  \0   i
0000020  \0   t  \0   y  \0   S  \0   t  \0   a  \0   t  \0   i  \0   o
0000040  \0   n  \0   E  \0   o  \0   I  \0   C  \0   o  \0   d  \0   e
0000060  \0  \n  \0   D  \0   E  \0   H  \0   E  \0   0  \0   4  \0   4
*
0000400  \0  \n  \0   D  \0   E  \0   H      \0   E  \0   0  \0   4  \0
0000420   4  \0  \n  \0   D  \0   E  \0   H  \0   E  \0   0  \0   4  \0
*
0422160   4  \0  \n  \n
0422164
```

Comment: Although this solved the immediate problem, it looks like the data was UTF-16, and you should probably use a real conversion tool (see comments on your question).

Comment: The file is in UTF-16. Removing the nulls will screw up any non-ASCII characters.